# Trim space and concatenate the lists in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I was trying to get a final list by eliminating the spaces and merging the lists. 
Let's consider i have two lists.

```
list1 = ['string1,1, 2','string2,2,3','string3,3,4']
list2 = ['string1 ,  5, 6','string2 ,  6, 7', 'string3,  8, 9']
```

My final list should be like below by eliminating the spaces before the elements in list2 and concatenating with list1.

```
list = ['string1,1,2,5,6','string2,2,3,6,7','string3,3,4,8,9']
```

Is there any way to achieve this?
I tired something like below, but didn't worked

```
list2 = [x for x in list2 if x.strip()]
list = list1+list2
```

Comment: `'string1,1, 2'`+`'string1 ,  5, 6'` will be `'string1,1,2string1,5,6'` after merging and removing spaces, but in your case it's `'string1,1,2,5,6'`, how?

Comment: list2 = [x.replace(" ","") for x in list2 ] , just replace space with empty string

Comment: `res = [','.join(x.split(',') + y.split(',')[1:]) for x,y in zip(list1, list2)]` And remove spaces like the comment above.

Comment: @knh190 your comment works assuming the first string needs to be removed, but we still need clarification from the OP. You can go ahead and add an answer if you want

Comment: Any reason for downvotes? While lacking some clear explanation of logic, it still provided mcve along with that OP has tried. Looks valid to me :P

Answer (score 2):

```
#replacing whitespaces
l1 = [x.replace(' ', '') for x in list1]
l2 = [x.replace(' ', '') for x in list2]

#returns a dictionary of items in list, for 'string1,2,3' key=string1, values=[2, 3]
def func(l):
     d = {}
     for i in l:
             d[i.split(',')[0]] = i.split(',')[1:]
     return d

l2_dict = func(l2)
#list with elements key corresponding to l1's key
l2_1 = [','.join(l2_dict[i.split(',')[0]]) if i.split(',')[0] in l2_dict else '' for i in l1]

result = [i + ',' + j for i,j in zip(l1, l2_1)]
```

Above will work even if we reorder the list2 elements.

Output:

```
['string1,1,2,5,6', 'string2,2,3,6,7', 'string3,3,4,8,9']
```

Comment: No. There is list comprehension favored over a `map`.

Comment: Thanks, updated! I am a Scala fan, recently learned python :)

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['string1,1, 2','string2,2,3','string3,3,4']
list2 = ['string1 ,  5, 6','string2 ,  6, 7', 'string3,  8, 9']

res =[]
for i, j in zip(list1,list2):
    tmp =  []
    tmp1 = [l.strip() for l in i.split(',')]
    tmp2=[l.strip() for l in j.split(',')]

    for k in tmp1:
        if k not in tmp:
            tmp.append(k.strip())
    for k in tmp2:
        if k not in tmp:
            tmp.append(k.strip())
    res.append(','.join(tmp))

print(res)
```

output

```
['string1,1,2,5,6', 'string2,2,3,6,7', 'string3,3,4,8,9']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
new_list = []
for i in list1:
  for j in list2:
    # remove the spaces
    x = i.replace(" ","").split(",")
    y = j.replace(" ","").split(",")

    # check if 1st element is same or not
    if x[0] == y[0]:
      result = ",".join(x+y[1:])
      new_list.append(result)

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['string1,1,2,5,6', 'string2,2,3,6,7', 'string3,3,4,8,9']
```

Answer (score 0):

strip() can only remove leading and trailing spaces from string. If you want to remove all Spaces from string you can use string.replace(" ", "") and your list comprehensions is not correct. Overall for removing spaces you need to do like this:

list2 = [x.replace(" ", "") for x in list2 ]

list1 = [x.replace(" ", "") for x in list1 ]

for details read here: [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
The rest of the part of your question regarding adding/ merging two lists is not fully clear. Assuming that you will merge and remove the recurring term then use the code from knh190 's comment :

```
res = [','.join(x.split(',') + y.split(',')[1:]) for x,y in zip(list1, list2)]
```